# Command prompt always pops up when logging on

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Every time I log on to my PC, this command prompt appears:

[image: VizorShortCut.exe in a command window]

What is this? How do I remove/disable it?

Comment: A quick google search reveals it part of Trend Micro AV. Do you have Trend Micro as your antivirus?

Comment: @GaneshR. Nope. I'm using `Security Essential`.

Comment: Then my suggestion is from Programs and Features check if you have Trend Micro installed. If yes, uninstall it. If no, you may need to install something like Avast Free or Avira Free and do a full scan of your drive.

Comment: @GaneshR. Thanks for your suggestions. Will try it later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Go to Control Panel --> Programs and Features and Uninstall Trend Micro AV if you see it there.

**If you are on windows 7 and earlier,** type **msconfig.exe** in the start menu and run it as administrator. Then go to the startup tab and untick all programs that have publisher Trend Micro AV.
**Otherwise,** you can find this option in the **task manager** *itself*.

If this doesn't fix your problem, just check if you have any program shortcuts under *C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup* and if you do, then remove all.

If all the above steps do not work for you, you can use a 3<sup>rd</sup> party program like [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to disable this startup.

Comment: Its "Programs and Features" in Control Panel in Windows 7....